# Can't ping machine on LAN from 1 out of 3 Kubuntus

Tags: wireless, networking, ping

I have three Kubuntu systems running, one 12.04 and two 13.10.  I have an HP MediaVault (a network attached storage device) on my LAN.

On the 12.04 and one of the 13.10's, I can ping hpmediavault; on the other 13.10 I get the "unknown host" error.  I've installed `winbind` on all three systems and set the **hosts** entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to

```
hosts:          wins files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

The misbehaving system has a wired connection; the other two have wireless connections.  That's the only difference I'm aware of that might affect this behavior.  I can ping the MediaVault on the third system by using its IP address.

So what do I need to do to get the third system to do its ping?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I also needed to install the `libnss-winbind` package, which wasn't mentioned in the instructions for connecting the MediaVault to Linux.  I don't know how that package got installed in 2 systems but not the third.  Installing it solved the problem.